# Move multiple files to subdirectories in linux

Tags: linux, directory, file-copy, move

I have a directory structure like this;

```
dir
├── dirA
│   └── file1
│   └── subdir
└── dirB
    └── file2
    └── subdir
```

I need to move file1 to dirA/subdir and file2 to dirB/subdir. How can I do it in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Gnu find**

```
find dir -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f -execdir sh -c 'mv -t ./*/ "$1"' find-sh {} \;
```

---

```
find dir \
  -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type f \
  -execdir sh -c '
        mv -t ./*/ "$1"
  ' find-sh {} \;
```

original directory structure

```
dir
├── dirA/
│   ├── fileA
│   └── subdir/
│       ├── e
│       ├── q
│       └── w
└── dirB/
    ├── fileB
    └── subdir/
        ├── c
        ├── x
        └── z
```

---

After the move operation

```
dir
├── dirA/
│   └── subdir/
│       ├── e
│       ├── fileA
│       ├── q
│       └── w
└── dirB/
    └── subdir/
        ├── c
        ├── fileB
        ├── x
        └── z
```

Answer (score 3):

From `dir` you could `mv dirA/file1 /dirA/subdir/` and `mv dirB/file2 /dirB/subdir/` are you trying to do this in a script or with a single command?

Jason C.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me to move various .yml files in various repo directories into a "tasks" sub directory in each of the repo directories:

```
for dir in */; do mv -- "$dir"*.yml "${dir}tasks/"; done
```

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the syntax correction, worked before but I agree w/ your correction.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you could do:

```
cd dir || exit
for dir in *(N-/); do
  subdirs=($dir/*(N-/))
  nondirs=($dir/*(N^-/))
  if (( $#subdirs != 1 || $#nondirs == 0 )); then
    print -ru2 Skipping $dir which has $#subdirs subdirs and $#nondirs nondirs.
  else
    mv -- $nondirs $subdirs/
  fi
done
```

Where we move the non-directory files only if there's only one subdirectory.

Note that with the `-` glob qualifier, the type of the files is determined *after* symlink resolution, and that symlinks might become broken after being moved (like if their target starts with `nameofsubdir` or `..`). Hidden files and dirs are ignored.

Answer (score -2):

Do this command in your shell:

```
mv file1 /dir/dirA
mv file2 /dir/dirB**
```

mv stands for move

`mv "filename.txt" "location/where/you/want/file/to/go"`

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Please only post answers that actually address the question. `mv file1 /dir/dirA` does not move `file1` to `dirA/subdir`. Besides, your answer should not reiterate feedback that has already been given; in this case, you don't add anything to the [first answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/635903/144217).